# issue with while loop in python

Tags: python, variable-alias

I am unable to figure out why the while loop in the following program
always stops after 1 iteration. Basically how is weightsPrevious becoming 
equal to weights after one iteration regardless of the input. Basically I want
to keep track of weights list for two consecutive runs and if they are equal
I want to exit. If I use a for loop with a fixed large number of iterations, I see
that consecutive weights lists are not equal in the first iteration, yet the while loop always
quits after one. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import random

def test(inputs, targets):
    inputDim = len(inputs[0])
    outputDim = len(targets[0])
    if (len(inputs) == len(targets)):
        dataSize = len(inputs)
    else:
        return

    weights = [];

    for i in range(inputDim + 1):
        weights.append([]);
        for j in range(outputDim):
            weights[i].append(2*random.random() - 1);

    weightsPrevious = 0

    iterCount = 0
    while (weightsPrevious != weights):
        iterCount += 1
        print("iteration", iterCount)
        weightsPrevious = weights.copy()
        for k in range(dataSize):
            for j in range(outputDim):
                weights[0][j] += 0.25*(targets[k][j] - 1)*(-1)
                for i in range(inputDim):
                    weights[i + 1][j] += 0.25*(targets[k][j] - 1)*inputs[k][i]

        return weights

test([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]],[[0],[1],[1],[1]])
```

EDIT: I get the same result even after removing the last return statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is happening because you've a `return` at the end of while loop. `return` stops the execution of the function and returns `weights`.

I think you need to unindent it :

```
while (weightsPrevious != weights):
    iterCount += 1
    print("iteration", iterCount)
    ...

return weights # now this is going to be executed when 
               # the while loop is finished.
```

Comment: thats exactly how had it in my test file, wonder why it copy pasted this way. but it still does not seem to work.

Comment: I just tried by deleting the return statement completely and the program still halts after one iteration

Comment: @BM One reason could be this line :`weightsPrevious = weights.copy()`, 
so, `weightsPrevious` becomes equal to  `weights` after first iteration, and will exit in the before the 2nd iteration.

Comment: Yeah, seems like this is the case. I ran the code in a Python visualizer and seem like although different lists are created the entries within the list are pointing to the same values. I tried using list(weights) instead, but that also does the same thing. Seems like I would need to find a new way to copy. Thanks for your responses and comments

Comment: @BM I explained this thing in detail yesterday, you may find it helpful :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599175/python-list-and/17599215#17599215

Comment: Awesome!! deepcopy fixes the issue. Although I had thought shallow copy would have been enough with floats.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (weightsPrevious != weights):
    iterCount += 1
    print("iteration", iterCount)
    weightsPrevious = weights.copy()
    for k in range(dataSize):
        for j in range(outputDim):
            weights[0][j] += 0.25*(targets[k][j] - 1)*(-1)
            for i in range(inputDim):
                weights[i + 1][j] += 0.25*(targets[k][j] - 1)*inputs[k][i]

    return weights
```

should be

```
while (weightsPrevious != weights):
    iterCount += 1
    print("iteration", iterCount)
    weightsPrevious = weights.copy()
    for k in range(dataSize):
        for j in range(outputDim):
            weights[0][j] += 0.25*(targets[k][j] - 1)*(-1)
            for i in range(inputDim):
                weights[i + 1][j] += 0.25*(targets[k][j] - 1)*inputs[k][i]

return weights
```

notice the indentation on the return

Comment: I had it indented this way in python, and i still get the same result. I deleted that line and aligned the indent with the while statement again just to make sure, but i still get the same result.

Comment: I just tried by deleting the return statement completely and the program still halts after one iteration