# Python function replacing input variable

Tags: python, list, function

I'm finding some weird behavior in python that I can't explain.  I've written the following function:

```
def process_data(data_in, unique_recs_in):
    recs = unique_recs_in
    for x, dat in enumerate(recs):
        recs[x].append(data_in.count(dat))
    return recs
```

where data_in and unique_recs_in are lists of lists. 'data_in' counts represents receptors, with a list being stored for each receptor each time in fails a critera.  'Unique_recs_in' is a list of all the unique receptor locations.

What I can't figure out is when I call this function, my output 'recs' returns properly.  However, 'unique_recs_in' changes when I run the function and is identical to 'recs'.  I have bug tested the code and can confirm that it's in this function that that happens.  Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: sample input below

data_in

```
[['631507.40000', '4833767.20000', '60.00'], ['631507.40000', '4833767.20000', '63.00'], ['631507.40000', '4833767.20000', '66.00']]
```

unique_recs_in:

```
[['631552.90000', '4833781.00000', '24.00'], ['631569.50000', '4833798.80000', '48.00'], ['631589.20000', '4833745.50000', '12.00']]
```

Comment: Can you give some sample input/output which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`recs = unique_recs_in` simply creates a new reference to the list object, to get a completely new copy of a list of lists use `copy.deepcopy`.

```
>>> lis = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> a = lis
>>> a.append(4)     #changes both `a` and `lis`
>>> a, lis
([[1, 2], [3, 4], 4], [[1, 2], [3, 4], 4])
```

Even a shallow copy is not enough for list of lists:

```
>>> a = lis[:]
>>> a[0].append(100) #Inner lists are still same object, just the outer list has changed.
>>> a, lis
([[1, 2, 100], [3, 4]], [[1, 2, 100], [3, 4]])
```

`copy.deepcopy` returns a completely new copy:

```
>>> import copy
>>> a = copy.deepcopy(lis) 
>>> lis
[[1, 2, 100], [3, 4], 4]
>>> a.append(999)
>>> a, lis
([[1, 2, 100], [3, 4], 4, 999], [[1, 2, 100], [3, 4], 4])
>>> a[0].append(1000)
>>> a, lis
([[1, 2, 100, 1000], [3, 4], 4, 999], [[1, 2, 100], [3, 4], 4])
```

If the list contains only immutable objects, then only a shallow copy is enough:

```
recs = unique_recs_in[:]
```

---

You might find this helpful as well: [Python `list([])` and `[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17599215/846892)

Comment: I never knew this; go figure.  Thanks for the sample code, that's really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to store in `recs` a *copy* of `unique_recs_in` so it wont be modified. Try with this:

```
recs = [l[:] for l in unique_recs_in] # although Ashwini `deepcopy` is more elegant
```

By assigning a list to another list `l1=l2` you're just establishing and alias between them (ie: both variables reference to the same list in memory) so modifying one will modify the other (because they are the same).

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will produce a shallow copy, which won't entirely separate the two. For instance, appending to `recs[x]` will still affect the xth value of `unique_recs_in`

Comment: @Kevin Good point, I missed that, probably not what OP wants, I'll modify the answer. Thank you!