# What does listing do to a array?

Tags: python

For example, considering a variable test_set which is an array of numbers

list(test_set) #returns all the values in the test_set

print(test_set)#returns <torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset object at 0x7f1bf94d1c10> which isn't anything

Why is there a difference? Does list do anything to the test_set?

Comment: It does nothing _to_ the array, but creates a new plain Python list from it (as opposed to a different kind of collection, e.g. set, dict, numpy array, or in this case, Torch data set).

Answer (score 0):

[List()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list) is a built in function in python.

It transform all python object with `__iter__()` function into a new List object.

More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581397/what-does-the-list-function-do-in-python)